grep command until a specific column
Can someone help with how I can use Grep cmd to get a specific output.
My cmd -------- ps -aef | grep gen | grep -v grep
cor     3957      1  0 Mar01 ?        02:04:07 gen nam=RS grp=81
mre  103189      1  1 Feb22 ?        16:16:37 gen nam=AB grp=05
cor   169727 169668  0 Apr11 pts/1    00:01:27 gen

I only want the output of 3rd row which end with 'gen'. I dont want any data in my grep after column 8.

Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Tip: use grep [g]en and eliminate the grep -v grep to save a process.

awk is probably a more appropriate tool

Even better: pgrep.

"I only want the output of 3rd row which end with 'gen'. I dont want any data in my grep after column 8."
If you want only the output of the 3rd row, use awk 'NR==3'.  If you want all rows in which the 8th column is "gen", use awk '$8 == "gen"'.  If you only want the first 8 columns of the row in which the 8th column is "gen", use:
awk '$8 == "gen"{ for(i=9; i <= NF; i++) $i=""; print}'

